# Let $G$ be the graph whose vertices are binary sequences of length 4, two vertices are adjacent if they have exactly 2 bits different. Is it planar?

Tags: graph-theory

> Given $G$, a graph whose vertices are binary sequences of length 4. Two vertices are adjacent in $G$ if and only if they differ by ***exactly*** two bits. Is it planar?

Here's what I tried to say:

> I tried to disprove that it is planar first. I wrote so many examples trying to get $K_5$ and $K_{3,3}$ but have not succeeded. Then I thought about the Cubic graph which is built of sequences of length $3$ and two vertices are connected if and only if they differ by exactly $1$ bit as I remember, but given that our $G$ is of length $4$ this is not helpful at all.

Any direction would be appreciated! Perhaps calculating the number of edges?

Comment: Check for presence of cycles of length $3$; planar graphs without such cannot have too many edges.

Comment: Your title says two bits different, the question says three.  Which is it?

Comment: Oh I am very sorry. Edited.

Comment: @TheNotMe Actually it is not planar in both versions. The argument is slightly different, but the basic idea is the same: use the bound on the number of edges.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**First problem** If they differ in exactly $2$ bits.

Then each vertex has degree $\binom{4}{2}=6$. Since any planar graph has a vertex of degree at most $5$, the graph cannot be planar.

**P.S.** If you don't know this, you can use the fact that in any planar graph you have

$$e \leq 3v-6 \,.$$

Your graph fails this relation. The proof of this result is pretty simple, it can be found in almost any textbook on graph Theory.

---

**Second problem** If they differ in exactly $3$ bits.

**Hint** Your graph is bi-partite, since the vertices of any edge have odd/even number of ones.

In any bi-partite planar graph (more generarily in any planar graph without triangles) you have

$$e \leq 2v-4 \,.$$

**P.S.** This is probably easier: prove first that any planar graph without triangles has a vertex of degree at most $3$.

Comment: I do not think it is bipartite. A graph is bipartite if and only if it is two-colorable. Take the subgraph of our $G$ to be of the vertices $1010, 0110, 1100$. All these are connected to each other (they form a triangle,) and are not 2-colorable.

Comment: @TheNotMe You said they differ in $3$ bits!

Comment: I am very sorry, someone indicated the typo. Was an honest typo. Sorry again! It is 2 bits.

Comment: @TheNotMe Doesn't matter, included solutions to both versions.

Comment: Thank you so much! Again, sorry for my typo. And oh, the solution for $2$ bits. I calculated the degree of each vertex but did not know that a planar graph has a vertex of degree at most $5$!

Comment: @TheNotMe If you know that in any planar graph you have $e \leq 3v-6$, your graph fails that relation. The vertex of degree 5 is a consequence of this.

Comment: That I do know, but how is it a consequence of that? (Excuse my questions, still trying to figure out the ways of solving Graph-Theory questions)

Comment: @TheNotMe The sum of degrees is $2e \leq 6v-12$. Assume by contradiction that all vertices have degree at least $6$, the the sum of degrees is $ \geq 6v$. Thus $6v-12 \geq 2e \geq 6v$. Contradiction.

Comment: @TheNotMe But as i said, for this problem, count the edges and you'll see that your graph fails $e \leq 3v-6$.

Comment: Thank you so much! Truly, much appreciated!